# Cannot read data from firebase - Firebase DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have created a simple app on which a user can register an login. authentication is working perfectly. I have also added a real-time database. I am getting "permission denied" when i try to read the data from firebase, despite the "write data" is working perfect.
 I want to fetch the data for logged in user.
    here are firebase rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the write method(this works perfect):

```
public void writeUserInfo(){
        String username = etUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String age = etAge.getText().toString().trim();
        String sex = etSex.getText().toString().trim();

        if(username.isEmpty()){
            etUserName.setError("user name required");
            etUserName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(age.isEmpty()){
            etAge.setError("age required");
            etAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(sex.isEmpty()){
            etSex.setError("sex required");
            etSex.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        User user = new User(username,age,sex);
        mDatabase.child("users/"+firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(user);
    }
```

And this is the read method:

```
public void readUserData(){
        mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //array list to staore user data as elements
                    ArrayList<User> userData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User element = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        userData.add(element);
                    }

                    for(User user: userData){
                        etUserName.setText(user.getmUsername());
                        etAge.setText(user.getmAge());
                        etSex.setText(user.getmSex());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

here is the database hierarchy:
[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQBi.jpg)
I am also including login and signup methods:

Login method:

```
public void signIn(){
        String userEmail = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPassword = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //validation
        //validation
        if(userEmail.isEmpty()){
            etEmail.setError("Email is required");
            //et is focused
            etEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(userEmail).matches()){
            etEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
            //focus et
            etEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(userPassword.isEmpty()){
            etPassword.setError("Password is required");
            //et is focused
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(userPassword.length()<6){
            etPassword.setError("Password length should be atleast 6 characters");
            //request focus
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //setting progress bar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //firebase signin method
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                //hiding progress bar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profile.class);
                    //this flag will clear all the open activities
                    //so that user cant go back to login activyty upon pressing
                    //back button
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logged in successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is the signUp method:

```
public void userRegistration(){
        String userEmail = etSignupEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String userPassword = etSignupPassword.getText().toString().trim();


        //validation
        if(userEmail.isEmpty()){
            etSignupEmail.setError("Email is required");
            //et is focused
            etSignupEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(userEmail).matches()){
            etSignupEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
            //focus et
            etSignupEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(userPassword.isEmpty()){
            etSignupPassword.setError("Password is required");
            //et is focused
            etSignupPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(userPassword.length()<6){
            etSignupPassword.setError("Password length should be atleast 6 characters");
            //request focus
            etSignupPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //showing progressbar upon regisration process lifetime
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //calling firebase register users methods via mAuth instance
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                //changing visibility of progress bar to gone upon registration
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //checking if the process was successful
                //using this task obj
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"user registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    //this line checks whether the email is already registered or not
                    //using the task obj and FirebasesuthUSerCollisonException
                    if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"email already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I cannot figure what has gone wrong. Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't include your solution in your question. Questions are for questions and answers are for answers :) If you think your solution adds something to the other answers feel free to post it. There is absolutely nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: @AndréKool okay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read from `/users` here:

```
mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

But your rules only gives a user access to `/users/$uid`. Since the user doesn't have read permission on `/users`, the listener gets rejected.

If you want to read the user's own data, read that specific child node:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Now since the user has read permission to their own node, the listener will be allowed.

Comment: This worked!! I have further changed the read method and now it's working as required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure app name and client id are same as in firebase console.

If you are not sure re-download google-services.json from your project's console and add it your project.

and also change your rules during development and testing period to this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```